# zookeeper sasl authentication issue

Tags: authentication, apache-zookeeper, jaas, sasl

I am trying to have setup SASL authentication for my zookeeper for Kafka. I followed all the steps mentioned in below link

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/ZOOKEEPER/Client-Server+mutual+authentication

Below is my server_jaas.conf file kept in /home directory

```
Server {
   org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required
   username="admin"
   password="admin-secret"
   user_admin="admin-secret"
};
```

Below is my java.env file configuration

```
SERVER_JVMFLAGS="-Djava.security.auth.login.config=/home/server_jaas.conf"
```

Below is the error I get

```
2017-08-01 16:49:40,774 [myid:] - ERROR [main:ServerCnxnFactory@199] - No JAAS configuration section named 'Server' was foundin '/home/server_jaas.conf'.
2017-08-01 16:49:40,774 [myid:] - ERROR [main:ZooKeeperServerMain@64] - Unexpectked exception, exiting abnormally
java.io.IOException: No JAAS configuration section named 'Server' was foundin '/home/server_jaas.conf'.
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.ServerCnxnFactory.configureSaslLogin(ServerCnxnFactory.java:200)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxnFactory.configure(NIOServerCnxnFactory.java:82)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServerMain.runFromConfig(ZooKeeperServerMain.java:117)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServerMain.initializeAndRun(ZooKeeperServerMain.java:87)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServerMain.main(ZooKeeperServerMain.java:53)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain.initializeAndRun(QuorumPeerMain.java:116)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain.main(QuorumPeerMain.java:78)
```

Comment: @Igor were you ever able to figure out what the problem was? I ran into the same issue and have been banging my head for quite a while now.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding ; to the end of your server definition

```
Server {
   org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required
   username="admin"
   password="admin-secret"
   user_admin="admin-secret";
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The content of config file could be like this:

```
Server {
   org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required
   username="admin"
   password="admin-secret"
   user_admin="admin-secret";
};
```

and make sure the location of `/home/server_jaas.conf` is correct.

I got the same exception since I gave a wrong location of this config file.